# How can i check if the mysql query returns null

Tags: php, mysql

Here i want to check if the query in this function() returns null or not.

```
function ifproductValid($productID){
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT product_publish_status FROM product_list WHERE product_id='$productID'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
            //here i want to check if the result is null or not
        if($product_status == 1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        }       
        } else {
        echo "No results found";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

Based on the result i want to return true or false from this function. how can i check that?

Comment: So whats the problem replace No results found with false every thing will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
        if (is_null($row)) {
        // do something here
        }
    if($product_status == 1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }       
    } else {
    echo "No results found";
```

Comment: The parent code is closing the connection to the database at the end of the function. I think you should save the response in a variable and return it after.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to get only a single row from the database you don't need to do a while to iterate the results. I would do something like this:

```
function ifproductValid($productID){

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $response = false;

    if($conn->connect_error){

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT product_publish_status 
            FROM product_list WHERE product_id=' . $productID;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

        $dbResult = $result->fetch_assoc();

        if(!is_null($dbResult[0] && $dbResult[0]['product_publish_status'] == 1){

            $response = true;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
    return $response;
}
```

If you only want to be sure that the database rows will never be null, you can specify it on the sql so you don't will have to comprove it later.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT product_publish_status 
         FROM product_list 
         WHERE product_id = ' . $productID . ' 
             AND product_publish_status IS NOT NULL';
```